# PostgreSQL-1c-16 после сбоя питания не запускается сервис на WIndows 10

Tags: postgresql

Помогите пожалуйста, после сбоя питания перестал запускаться сервис postgre. Пишет - служба была запущена и затем остановлена. Типа никому не нужна...

Как это вылечить. Читал в Google про чистку логов, но там про 9 и 11, а у меня 16 posthgre.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте восстановление после сбоя. Для этого запустите в single

```
postgres   --single   -c config_file=/.../main/postgresql.conf   -D /.../main/   -P   -d 1
```

Восстановимые ошибки испраявятся и потом выходите и запускаете службу.

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек. Помогло. Дождался пока он 3 базы перемолотил и сервис действительно запустился. С разницей только в том, что у меня папки main нет и указал папку в котjрой лежит postgresql.conf. 
Сохраню себе эту строчку в памятку. Комп рабочий и свет то и дело отключают.

Comment: @asoft галочку и плюсик мне тогда;)